# How do I get Crystal Reports for Eclipse to notice my new POJO fields?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an existing Crystal Reports `.rpt` that uses POJOs for its data source.

I have added some new fields to my POJO.

How can I get Crystal Reports for Eclipse to show these new fields in the Field Explorer so I can use them in my `.rpt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the `Crystal Reports` top-level menu, choose `Verify Database...`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse plugin for Crystal Reports.  This has been my problem too. Go to the top level menu item "Crystal Reports" then choose "Verify Database...".
Select "Yes" to the warning.
Verify your new field(s) in the Field Explorer.